# mariadb: select distinct with complex columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb, distinct

I have tables like

```
key | value
item:yyy:revs:1 | somevalue
item:xxx:revs:0 | somevalue
item:yyy:revs:5 | somevalue
item:xxx:revs:3 | somevalue
```

I now want to select the rows for each item (xxx, yyy) with the highest revision number. In this example only:

```
item:yyy:revs:5 | somevalue
item:xxx:revs:3 | somevalue
```

Normally I would work with `distinct`, but because the "item id" is just a substring of the key column I don't know how to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can break up the "complex" column so that the value you need is in a column by itself? If so, the query is simple and performant. Otherwise we need a brute-force solution...

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('item:xxx:revs:3', ':', -1))
    FROM t
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX('item:xxx:revs:3', ':', 3);
```